# VB.Net For Loop won't execute

Tags: excel, vb.net, rpa, uipath

I have the below VB.Net code currently being executed in UiPath using the “Invoke Code” activity. The `For` loop does not give any syntax errors but the `If` statement does not seem to be executing. Is there a problem with the way I referenced the range in the loop (i.e., `ws.range("F" & i).Value`)?

```
'create instances of excel and open final file
Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim wb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
Dim ws As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("FilePath.xlsx")
    ws= DirectCast(wb.Worksheets(1),Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)
    
'Delete the first row of the worksheet
ws.Range("A1").EntireRow.Delete

'Define the last row of the worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Delete the last row (the Total column)
        ws.Range("A" & LastRow).EntireRow.Delete

LastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

Dim i As Long

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        If ws.range("F" & i).Value Is "Declined"  Then 
            ws.range("F" & i).EntireRow.ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
      
'Save and close application
excel.activeworkbook.save
excel.Workbooks.close()
excel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `If` condition will always return false because `Is` doesn't compare the content; it checks if two object references refer to the same object (yes, a string is an object), which in this case, is false.

Instead, you should use the `=` operator to compare two strings. However, since the compile-time type of `Range.Value` is `Object`, you have to convert it to a string first. Change your code to something like this:

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    Dim currentCell = ws.Range("F" & i)

    If currentCell.Value IsNot Nothing AndAlso currentCell.Value.ToString() = "Declined" Then
        currentCell.EntireRow.ClearContents()
    End If
Next
```

---

### References:

- [Comparison operators in VB.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/comparison-operators).
- [The `Is` operator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/is-operator)

Comment: @roses56 Note that in recent versions of VB, the condition can be shortened to `If CurrentCell.Value?.ToString() = "Declined" Then` (notice the `?` after `Value`), but since I never used UiPath before, I'm not sure if the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) is supported so I decided to go with the safest option.